# Do tyres heat while driving in the freezing weather?

Tags: thermodynamics, friction, cooling

I know that when I drive my car in a regular day tyres heat up due to friction with the street and sometimes the street temperature itself is too high that contribute to heating the tyres up even more

My question is about wintertime when the temperature is below 0 c.

do tyres heat up due to friction and movement on the street?

or do they cool up as the next point on the street the tyre is going to reach will be freezing, therefore tyres never heat in such weather?

Comment: Watch your tire pressure as you drive, if you have a tire pressure monitor system on your car. They definitely heat up as you drive.

Comment: Less to do with friction, more with deformation. Lower tire pressures result in more heating.

Comment: If it is winter in your hemisphere (or if you have a correspondent who is experiencing winter), this question is amenable to a straightforward experiment.

Answer (score 2):

The tire rolling will never make it colder than it was sitting idle.  The air is typically colder than the ground surface, so the tire surfaces touching air will be at least as cold if not colder *before* they touch the ground than after.

As other users have commented, friction, compression and agitation of the gas within the tires, and heat conduction from the hot car body will all conspire to heat the tires when moving compared to when stopped, regardless of the ambient temperature.

Comment: so? does it get hot or stay cool?